# Problem using similarity of triangles (I guess).

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral, quartics

I'm trying to answer the problem below using similarity of triangles, but wherever I go I got a fourth degree equation that is quite hard to solve. There's another way to solve this? I need a hint. Thanks!

[image]

I saw that $FD=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then I did

$BA/AE=FB/DE\Rightarrow 1/(1+x)^2=\sqrt{1-x^2}/x\Rightarrow0-x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1$

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: What did you do, and what equation did you get?

Comment: @saulspatz I got a quartic equation with nice solution.

Comment: I saw that $FD=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then I did. $BA/AE=FB/DE \implies 1/(1+x)^2=\sqrt{1-x^2}/x \implies 0=-x^4-2x^3-x^2+2x+1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Misunderstanding. I was asking the OP to show his attempts.  (Which he now has done, I see. )

Comment: I agree with your equation.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B2x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-2x-1%3D0&t=crmtb01) gives one positive solution, but it's rather unpleasant.  Where does this problem come from?  Any chance you're supposed to solve it numerically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(1+x)^2}}$$ or
$$x^4+2x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$ or
$$x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1-2x^2-4x-2=0$$ or
$$(x^2+x+1)^2-2(x+1)^2=0$$ or
$$(x^2+x+1+\sqrt2(x+1))(x^2+x+1-\sqrt2(x+1))=0$$ or
$$(x^2+(\sqrt2+1)x+1+\sqrt2)(x^2-(\sqrt2-1)x+1-\sqrt2)=0,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{\sqrt2-1+\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}}{2}.$$

Comment: Please, can you explain me what you did before and next the last "or" you wrote.

Comment: @Dunck Did you ask how I got $x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1=(x^2+x+1)^2$?

Comment: After that, the line below.

Comment: @Dunck I used $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$ I added something. See now.